# Is there any way to set a reminder's time to a later time than an event on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, reminder

For example, if I have an all-day event, it [will be triggered at 5PM the previous day](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/when-are-reminders-sent-for-google-calendar-all-day-events). What if I want to be notified about it on the same day though?

I was thinking I could do something like `-12 hours` so that it would remind me at 5AM the same day, but it converted it to `12 hours`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't support sending reminders after the event or after 5PM in the current time zone for All Day events and there is nothing we can do about it client side, since this is mostly happening server side.

Comment: Woops, I forgot to update this question with my findings in the other one. I fixed it though, so you might want to update your answer.

Comment: @Senseful I did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried yet, but maybe with google scripts:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/googleapps/appsscript/class_calendarevent.html#addEmailReminder